# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED at http://localhost:3000/ when running End-to-End testing by puppeteer

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement an End-to-End test on my React application after all 3 other steps of testing is completed. However, I am stuck on the aforementioned error. The project is running successfully on http://localhost:3000/.

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

describe('show/hide an event details', () => {
  let browser;
  let page;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    jest.setTimeout(30000);
    browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/');
    await page.waitForSelector('.event');
  });

  test('An event element is collapsed by default', async () => {
    const eventDetails = await page.$('.event .event__Details');
    expect(eventDetails).toBeNull();
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    browser.close();
  });

});
```